# Using Templates to resolve virtual methods

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2008, dispatch, visitor-pattern

This issue involves using templates to resolve virtual members in a Dispatch pattern.
*Note:  This is not the same as virtual template method questions already asked on StackOverflow*. *

**Edit 1:  Corrected syntax errors, added clarifications.**

Given the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Field_Interface
{
  public:
    virtual std::string  get_field_name(void) const = 0;
};

class Field_Integer : public Field_Interface
{
  public:
    std::string get_field_name(void) const
    { return "INT";}
};

class Field_String : public Field_Interface
{
  public:
    std::string get_field_name(void) const
    { return "VARCHAR";}
};

class Field_Double : public Field_Interface
{
  public:
    std::string get_field_name(void) const
    { return "DOUBLE";}
};


class Abstract_Visitor
{
  public:
  virtual void visit(const Field_Integer& fi) = 0;
  virtual void visit(const Field_String& fi) = 0;
  virtual void visit(const Field_Double& fi) = 0;
};

class Visitor_Name_Query_1 : public Abstract_Visitor
{
  public:
  template <class Field>
  void visit(const Field& f)
  {
      std::cout << "Field name is: "
                << f.get_field_name()
                << "\n";
  }
};

class Visitor_Name_Query_2 : public Abstract_Visitor
{
  public:
    void visit(const Field_Integer& fi)
    { print_field_name(fi); }

    void visit(const Field_String& fi)
    { print_field_name(fi); }

    void visit(const Field_Double& fi)
    { print_field_name(fi); }

  private:
    void print_field_name(const Field_Interface& fi)
    { 
        std::cout << "Field name is: "
                  << fi.get_field_name()
                  << "\n";
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Visitor_Name_Query_1    q1;
    Field_Integer           fi;
    q1.visit(f1);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is saying the templated method in `Visitor_Name_Query_1` is not resolving the abstract interface from `Abstract_Visitor`.

**Edit 2: Results from g++**

```
# g++ -o main.exe main.cpp
main.cpp: In function `int main()':
main.cpp:75: error: cannot declare variable `q1' to be of type `Visitor_Name_Query_1'
main.cpp:75: error:   because the following virtual functions are abstract:
main.cpp:35: error:  virtual void Abstract_Visitor::visit(const Field_Integer&)
main.cpp:36: error:  virtual void Abstract_Visitor::visit(const Field_String&)
main.cpp:37: error:  virtual void Abstract_Visitor::visit(const Field_Double&)
main.cpp:77: error: `f1' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:77: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
```

`Visitor_Name_Query_1` is an attempt to simplify the class `Visitor_Name_Query_2`.  When the number of `visit` methods grows beyond a simple quantity (like 5), maintenance becomes tedious.  This is the reason for the `template` declaration.

When the template is expanded, with one of the field types, the declaration matches the one in `Visitor_Name_Query_2`.

So why is the compiler generating saying that `class Visitor_Name_Query_1` is abstract?

*Note:  I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows Vista.*

* <sub>The other posts involve using templates to create virtual method declarations.  I'm using templates to create functions that implement the abstract methods.</sub>

Comment: A class member template can not be virtual.

Comment: When you say "This is not the same as", do you in fact mean "this is exactly the same as"?

Comment: When I fix all the compiler errors which seem completely unrelated to your question (e.g. syntax errors and missing inheritance), then this compiles without even a warning in VC 2013.

Comment: @ChristianHackl [It doesn't compile with `Visitor_Name_Query_1` class instantiated](http://rextester.com/EXHRJ22696), of course.

Comment: Use the template. The `Abstract_Visitor` is unnecessary, so get rid of it.

Comment: @Constructor: You are right. Well, I figure I should just have given up after the third syntax-error correction :)

Comment: @Constructor: Which template member is virtual?

Comment: @jxh - The `Abstract_Visitor` defines an interface that is used in this example and other examples; so it is needed.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not using a template to define the virtual methods.  I am using a template as short-hand notation to generate all the functions that will resolve the interface.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You assume that specializations of `template <class Field> void visit(const Field& f)` class member template override corresponded overloads of the virtual method `visit` of the `Abstract_Visitor` base class, don't you? Then the specializations of the `visit` class member template should be virtual...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why is the compiler generating saying that class `Visitor_Name_Query_1` is abstract?

Because the standard says so. §14.5.2 [temp.mem]/p4:

> A specialization of a member function template does not override a
>   virtual function from a base class. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> class B {
>     virtual void f(int);
> };
> class D : public B {
>     template <class T> void f(T); // does not override B::f(int)
>     void f(int i) { f<>(i); }     // overriding function that calls
>                                   // the template instantiation
> };
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you really want the `Abstract_Visitor` to have a default implementation. If you move the `template` into the `Abstract_Visitor`, you can let each `virtual` visitor have the default implementation.

```
class Abstract_Visitor
{
  template <class Field>
  void visit(const Field& f)
  {
      std::cout << "Field name is: "
                << f.get_field_name()
                << "\n";
  }
  public:
  virtual void visit(const Field_Integer& fi) { visit<>(fi); }
  virtual void visit(const Field_String& fi) { visit<>(fi); }
  virtual void visit(const Field_Double& fi) { visit<>(fi); }
};
```

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a default implementation.  I have cases where many, if not all, the `visit` functions are processed in the same way, such as the printing example in my question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Thanks for the clarification, but can you explain how that is different from a default implementation? Also, how do you feel this approach prevents you from implementing a different kind of visitor for a different kind of type?

Answer (score 0):

As all field types have a common interface, you could simplify the problem by changing the interface if it is possible:

```
class Abstract_Visitor
{
  public:
  virtual void visit(const Field_Interface& f) = 0;
};

class Visitor_Name_Query_3 : public Abstract_Visitor
{
  public:
  void visit(const Field_Interface& f)
  {
      std::cout << "Field name is: "
                << f.get_field_name()
                << "\n";
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, I do have visitors like this, where the `Field_Interface` visitor catches the field types that are not implemented (visited).